# In Shell script process variables in text

Tags: shell, variables, sh

I have a file 'test.txt', the contents is "SomeText_$(date '+%Y%m%d')".
When reading this into a variable with:

```
txt=`cat test.txt`
```

Then I try to print with

```
echo $txt
```

This prints: "SomeText_$(date '+%Y%m%d')"
How do I print this so I receive "SomeText_20200904"

Answer (score 1):

The posted `echo` will display the content from `$txt` but not execute anything else.
The second line here with `eval` will read and process what follows then execute the result as a shell command

```
txt=`cat test.txt`
eval echo $txt
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. This is good, I realised I need to save the result with 'result=$(eval echo "$txt"). One issue which this has raised, I only want to evaluate variables like $(some var), not things like '(' or '*'. Do you know a way of ignoring these?